# Waiting in a while loop on an async function (Node.js/ES6)

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I'm writing a Windows Node.js server app (using ES6 btw).

The first thing I want to do - in the top-level code - is sit in a while loop, calling an async function which searches for a particular registry key/value. This function is 'proven' - it returns the value data if found, or else throws:

```
async GetRegValue(): Promise<string> { ... }
```

I need to sit in a while loop until the registry item exists, and then grab the value data. (With a delay between retries).
I think I know how to wait for an async call to complete (one way or the other) before progressing with the rest of the start-up, but I can't figure out how to sit in a loop waiting for it to *succeed*.

Any advice please on how to achieve this?
(I'm fairly new to typescript, and still struggling to get my head round all async/await scenarios!)

Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks guys. I know I was 'vague' about my code - I didn't want to put my real/psuedo code attempts, since they have all probably overlooked the points you can hopefully help me understand.
So I just kept it as a textual description... I'll try though:

```
async GetRegValue(): Promise<string> {

    const val: RegistryItem = await this.GetKeyValue(this.KEY_SW, this.VAL_CONN);
    return val.value
}

private async GetKeyValue(key: string, name: string): Promise<RegistryItem> {

    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new this.Registry({
            hive: this.Hive, key
        }).get(name, (err, items) => {

            if (err) {
                reject(new Error('Registry get failed'));
            }
            else {
                resolve( items );
            }
        });
    })
        .catch(err => { throw err });
}
```

So I want to do something like:

```
let keyObtained = false
let val
while (keyObtained == false)
{
    // Call GetRegValue until val returned, in which case break from loop
    // If exception then pause (e.g. ~100ms), then loop again
    }
}

// Don't execute here till while loop has exited

// Then use 'val' for the subsequent statements
```

As I say, GetRegValue() works fine in other places I use it, but here I'm trying to pause further execution (and retry) until it does come back with a value

Comment: use `await` or `then`.

Comment: Can you provide a better example of what you are doing?

Comment: Please provide the actual code for the thing you're trying to do a `while` loop on.  You can't do a `while` loop spin in Javascript waiting for something to happen because that hogs the single thread of JS and the thing you're waiting for can never run itself.  So, we need to see the actual code and understand what it is you are actually waiting for in order to best advise how else to code this.  Real code, real data you are waiting for, please.  Include as much detail as possible.

Comment: Javascript is an event-driven language.  That means the efficient way to know when something occurs is to register an event listener for an event triggered by the thing you're waiting for.  You don't poll it, you don't `while()` loop it, etc...  How to set up an event listener for the change you want depends entirely upon what it is which you do not disclose so we cannot answer your question as is.

Comment: The best design here would be for the code that updates the registry to expose an event or a callback that you can register an interest for.  You don't want to be `polling` a value in node.js (enormously inefficient).  You don't show what this `Registry` object is.  Perhaps it has its own events you can register for.  If not, then you should centralize all code that modifies the Registry and create some sort of notification other code can register for when a certain value is changed.  That will create an event-driven solution which is the appropriate way to program in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just use recursion. Here is an example on how you can keep calling the `GetRegValue` function until is resolves using the `retryReg` function below.

If the catch case is hit, it will just call `GetRegValue` over and over until it resolves successfully.

you should add a counter in the catch() where if you tried x amount of times you give up.

Keep in mind I mocked the whole `GetRegValue` function, but given what you stated this would still work for you.

```js
let test = 0;

function GetRegValue() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      test++;

      if (test === 4) {
        return resolve({
          reg: "reg value"
        });
      }

      reject({
        msg: "not ready"
      });

    }, 1000);
  });
}

function retryReg() {
  GetRegValue()
    .then(registryObj => {
      console.log(`got registry obj: ${JSON.stringify(registryObj)}`)
    })
    .catch(fail => {
      console.log(`registry object is not ready: ${JSON.stringify(fail)}`);
      retryReg();
    });
}

retryReg();
```

Comment: Since the OP included no detail at all about what they're actually doing, this is a wild, wild guess that may or may not be appropriate.  We have no idea if it is or not.

Comment: Oh, I'm coding in Typescript, btw

Comment: @ColH The same concept I'm trying to convey to you is still valid for typescript

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need this line:

```
.catch(err => { throw err });
```

The loop condition of `while` isn't much use in this case, as you don't really need a state variable or expression to determine if the loop should continue:

```
let val;
while (true)
{
    try {
       val = await GetRegValue(/* args */);
       break;

    } catch (x) {
        console.log(x); // or something better
    }

    await delay(100);
}
```

If the assignment to `val` succeeds, we make it to the `break;` statement and so we leave the loop successfully. Otherwise we jump to the `catch` block and log the error, wait 100 ms and try again.

It might be better to use a `for` loop and so set a sensible limit on how many times to retry.

Note that `delay` is available in an [npm package of the same name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay). It's roughly the same as:

```
await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 100));
```

Comment: While this might work, a "polling" loop in node.js is never the best design as it can waste all sorts of CPU just checking a variable over and over.  Much better to go to the source of the changed data and create an event-driven system which matches the overall architecture of node.js and would be much more efficient.

Comment: @jfriend00 sure if we are the author of the system providing the data. But frequently in distributed systems we have to simulate reliability by lashing together unreliable services that we have no control over. Retrying is an essential tool in such cases.

Comment: I'm just pointing out to the OP that this is NOT the best way to solve this problem.  From the snippets of the OP's code it looks like they control the code for `GetRegValue()` and, as such, may  also control the code for setting values.  If they do, they can just derive from `EventEmitter` or add an `EventEmitter` as instance data and create a notification system which is the "right" way to solve problems like this.  I would NEVER put a loop like this in production code that was suppose to scale.  Imagine you have one or more of these loops for every active user on your system.

Comment: I'd offer my own answer with a notification system if the OP showed more of the relevant code to allow us to see enough to show them a better way, but they don't show enough of the code.

Comment: I've decided to answer the question, as asked, because it's perfectly possible for OP to have a valid reason for wanting to do this. You may be assuming every function someone writes is running in a server app, per user request, with thousands of concurrent users. This is a tiny percentage of all software. Some things are designed to happen once a week, but they need to complete successfully with high probability. That's what retrying is for.

Comment: And, I'm making sure the OP understands that if this is a server, this is not the best way to do things - that's the purpose of comments, to add commentary to answers that might be useful to other readers.  You can just let my comment stand for the OP's benefit rather than getting all argumentative.  I also note that there is no mention at all in your answer that this type of solution is only appropriate for certain circumstances and could be a very bad design for a busy server or any process that could have a lot of these loops.

Comment: Thanks all. Only just got to work so yet to fully absorb all the suggestions. But to add some info that I didn't make clear: 
The app will have only one of these loops, at startup - the registry value tells it where to fetch its runtime config from, and (e.g. after installation) it will sit here waiting for that to be set (by a different app) before it is able to proceed further with startup. 
GetKeyValue() is being used to fetch the registry value, I don't control any of the lower code (it uses the 'node-winreg' package)